# C# Type Inference Gets the Wrong Type

Tags: c#, casting, unboxing

I created the following property, which threw an `InvalidCastException` if the getter was accessed when `ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT]` was `null`.

```
public long TotalRecordCount
{
    get { return (long)(ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1); }
    set { ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] = value; }
}
```

My thought is that it incorrectly attempted to unbox the object in `ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT]` to an `int`, which failed because it contained a `long`, but I think there might be a flaw in that logic. I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to point out that flaw.

I have since changed that property to read

```
public long TotalRecordCount
{
    get { return (long?)ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1; }
    set { ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] = value; }
}
```

which works just swell. Still, I am left wondering what was wrong with my original version... StackOverflow to the rescue?

Note that if i try to execute `(long)(ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1)` in the Immediate Window, I get the error message `Cannot unbox 'ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1' as a 'long'` and if I execute `(ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1).GetType().Name` I get `Int32`. I can execute `(long)-1` and end up with -1 as an `Int64`...so what's up?

Comment: Put that value in session! Leave ViewState for the UI only, dude.

Comment: This might help you understand what is going on here. http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: Session isn't tab-friendly, by the way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The return type of `ViewState` indexer is `Object` (I assume you mean ASP.NET viewstate here). Now consider what the compiler has to do when it sees this (which is equivalent to your code):

```
object o = ViewState[...];
var x = o ?? -1;
```

It has to deduce the result type of expression `o ?? -1` somehow. On the left it sees an `object`, on the right is an `int`. Clearly, the most general type for this expression is also `object`. However, this means that if it actually ends up using that `-1` (because `o` was null), it will have to convert it to `object` - and for an `int`, this means boxing.

So `x` is of type `object`, and it may contain an `int` (and maybe also some other integral type - we don't know what is in your viewstate, it could be `short`, for example). Now you write:

```
long y = (long)x;
```

Since `x` is `object`, this is unboxing. However, you can only unbox value types into exact same type (with the only exception being that you can substitute a signed type for an equivalent unsigned type, and enum for its underlying base type). That is, you cannot unbox `int` into `long`. A far simpler way to repro this, with no "extra" code, would be:

```
object x = 123;
long y = (long)x;
```

Which also throws `InvalidCastException`, and for exact same reason.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and complete explanation. I will sleep much better tonight!

Answer (score 5):

A cast has to be one step only.

The expression `<object> ?? <int>` will produce another object, and when the first value is null, ie. `ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT]` is null, then the resulting value will be an object, with a boxed Int32 in it.

Since you cannot unbox an object containing an Int32 to a long, you need to first unbox it to an Int32, and then cast it to a long.

Answer (score 1):

In your original, if you break it down, you were doing:

```
(ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1)
```

The [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is specifially designed to:

> to define a default value for a **nullable value types** as well as **reference types.**

In your case, you're using it to handle a System.Object, so it's going to take your "-1", treat it as an Int32, and box it into a new System.Object.  Then, it tries to unbox the Int32 into a long, which fails, since the cast cannot unbox and change the type in a single step.

You can solve this easily by specifying that your -1 is a long by using the L suffix:

```
public long TotalRecordCount
{
    get { return (long)(ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1L); }
    set { ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] = value; }
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem. Using ?? with a value type would be a compile-type error.

Comment: Using `??` with a non-nullable value type on the left side would cause a compile-time error though. Also, the return type of `ViewState.this[]` is `object` which is obviously a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

The problems is not the unboxing of the `ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT]`, the problem is the boxing and unboxing of the -1.

```
   ViewState[TOTAL_RECORD_COUNT] ?? -1
```

You are using the ?? operator on "object" and "int". The resulting type is "object". This means the -1 will be boxed (as int) when the field does not exist in the view state.

Then your program crashes later when it tries to unbox the (int)-1 as a long.

Answer (score 0):

[Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) is a value type, so casting `null` to a value type will always throw an exception (`NullReferenceException`). And casting an Int32 to Int64 will succeed and will not throw an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something he's not trying to cast null though? He has the null coalescing operator on the end.

Comment: i think you need to read the code a bit more closely...the actual cast that is failing is attempting to cast -1 to an Int64